# Anaconda navigator doesn t open

Tags: anaconda

I have the following error when trying to open

(base) D:\Anaconda>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 99, in main
from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\logs.py", line 18, in 
from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config_*init*_.py", line 27, in 
from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\main.py", line 104, in 
CONF = UserConfig(
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\user.py", line 219, in **init**
self.load_from_ini()
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\user.py", line 277, in load_from_ini
self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
self._read(fp, filename)
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\configparser.py", line 1017, in _read
for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 8: invalid start byte

Comment: good day dear Felix - we need to know how you did the install. Plz provide more infos